# SQL : how to Case depending of the result of the 2 latest values of one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am discovering SQL as I have to build queries in my new company.I have understood the basic but here is where I am stuck, maybe you could help me figure this out :

I would like to mention a product as unprocurable if sellers rejected my orders twice. Tricky part I aggregate the furniture orders for all our local offices, therefore even though I sent my purchase order(s) to one unique seller (the one with the best offer at the moment) I might have multiple lines for each item (one per office)

See below table for purchase orders, see REF1 item should be set as unprocurable as both on 21 and 31 december my orders have been rejected (no matter the seller)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3W3E.jpg

So to put it in logic I would like to have something like this:

For each items with 2 latest purchase orders that were both made at different dates and rejected(0 value in the table) THEN attach a note to it saying "unprocurable" else put as procurable.

IF it was only 1 value I think I could go with

```
Select 
    item 
    , MAX(date) 
    , case 
         when confirmed_units = 0 
           then 'Unprocurable' 
           else 'procurable' 
      end 
From 
    purchase_table 
Where
    date between TO_DATE('01/01/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('{RUN_DATE_YYYY/MM/DD}', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

But now I need to check the two latest purchase orders and that are not from the same day.

I am a bit lost, could you give a hand please?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear... have you tried using something along the lines of:

```
SELECT TOP 2 etc, etc... order by [column]
```